# how to access to Beaglebone black Led using specific virtual address, in a bare metal code?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, beagleboneblack, bare-metal

I am working on bare metal code.
I am trying to access led in beaglebone black (ARMv7) using a virtual address, by configuring the mmu.

After going through any documents.
I found , ttbr0 will contain the translational table base address.
translational table will contain the page table entries.

I am confused looking at various docs and sample code of ptes.
How to map it to a specific virtual address range.

For example:-
My gpio address is 0x4804C134, and i want to access using virtual address 0x002xxxx.
how do i map it ? what should be the pte for this ?

Comment: so the led has nothing to do with it you want to know how to setup the mmu, you know how to access the led without the mmu yes?

Comment: the arm documentation is quite clear, the upper portion of the address is used as an offset to the base of the table, that entries lower two bits determines what type of entry this is and reacts accordingly.  what have you tried so far (show your data/tables/code/whatever) what did you expect and what happened (likely a crash as you have to get this perfectly right or fail).   Note: start with a one to one mapping before you start messing with changing the address.  start with a 1mb page first as that is straightforward.